# JPQL, get a list of objects which have a child list, avoid n+1 requests and only choose specific fields

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpql

I have the following entity `Project`:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = "roles")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Project {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private String name;

  private String description;

  private Boolean isArchived;

  private LocalDate archivedDate;

  private LocalDate creationDate;

  @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE")
  private Boolean invoicingActivated;

  @ManyToOne
  @NotNull
  private Order order;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private DefaultDailyEntrySettings defaultDailyEntrySettings;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<ProjectEmployee> projectEmployees;
}
```

I want to get all projects. Each project should also have their list of `projectEmployees`.

Thats the entity `ProjectEmployee`:

```
@Data
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"employee_id", "project_id"})})
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = "project")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ProjectEmployee {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JsonIgnore
  @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
  @NotNull
  private Project project;

  @ManyToOne
  @NotNull
  private Employee employee;

  @ManyToOne
  private ProjectEmployeeRole projectEmployeeRole;
}
```

To avoid n+1 queries, i wrote the following query:

```
@Query("SELECT project FROM Project project JOIN FETCH project.order ord JOIN FETCH ord.customer " +
          "LEFT JOIN FETCH project.projectEmployees projectEmployee LEFT JOIN FETCH project.defaultDailyEntrySettings " +
          "LEFT JOIN FETCH projectEmployee.employee LEFT JOIN FETCH projectEmployee.projectEmployeeRole")
List<Project> findAllProjectsInOneQuery();
```

This works, but it returns **all** properties of every single object. For example i´m only interested in the id and the name of `ord.customer`, i dont need all the other fields of `ord.customer` in this case. The problem with getting all the fields this way is that theres a lot of data being transmitted which i do not need in this case. To only select the ones i need and reduce the amount of data im sending over the internet i could do something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT new de.project.Project(project.id, project.name, " +
          "project.description, project.isArchived, project.archivedDate, " +
          "project.creationDate, project.invoicingActivated, project.order.id, " +
          "project.order.name, project.order.customer.id, project.order.customer.name) " +
          "FROM  Project project")
List<Project> findAllMinimal();
```

But as you see, i can´t get `project.projectEmployees` that way, because it´s a list and i do not think im able to pass a list via the constructor this way.

I tried:

```
@Query("SELECT new de.project.Project(project.id, project.name, " +
              "project.description, project.isArchived, project.archivedDate, " +
              "project.creationDate, project.invoicingActivated, project.order.id, " +
              "project.order.name, project.order.customer.id, project.order.customer.name, " +
              "projectEmployee.id) " +
              "FROM  Project project JOIN project.projectEmployees projectEmployee")
    List<Project> findAllMinimal();
```

But `projectEmployee.id` is just the id of the first `projectEmployee`, i do not think im able to pass all `projectEmployees` this way.

Is there any way to get all projects with their projectEmployees(and the other properties i listed in the query above) and specify which fields i would like to get? It does not have to be one query, a constant number of queries is fine. It should obviosuly just avoid n+1 queries.

**Edit:**

I came up with a workaround. Im using the following two queries:

```
@Query("SELECT new de.project.Project(project.id, project.name, " +
          "project.description, project.isArchived, project.archivedDate, " +
          "project.creationDate, project.invoicingActivated, project.order.id, " +
          "project.order.name, project.order.customer.id, project.order.customer.name) " +
          "FROM  Project project")
List<Project> findAllMinimal();

@Query("SELECT DISTINCT new de.projectemployee.ProjectEmployee(projectEmployee.id, " +
          "projectEmployee.employee.id, projectEmployee.employee.email, " +
          "projectEmployee.employee.firstName, projectEmployee.employee.lastName, " +
          "projectEmployee.employee.address, projectEmployee.employee.weeklyHoursEnabled, " +
          "projectEmployee.employee.weeklyHours, projectEmployee.employee.isArchived, " +
          "projectEmployee.employee.archivedDate, projectEmployee.project.id, projectEmployeeRole.id, " +
          "projectEmployeeRole.name, projectEmployeeRole.hourlyWage) FROM ProjectEmployee projectEmployee " +
          "LEFT JOIN projectEmployee.projectEmployeeRole projectEmployeeRole " +
          "WHERE projectEmployee.project IN :projects")
  List<ProjectEmployee> findByProjects(@Param("projects") List<Project> projects);
```

To give every project his projectEmployees i need some additional java code:

```
    List<Project> projects = projectRepository.findAllMinimal();
    List<ProjectEmployee> projectEmployees = projectEmployeeRepository.findByProjects(projects);
    Map<Long, List<ProjectEmployee>> projectIdToProjectEmployeesMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (ProjectEmployee projectEmployee : projectEmployees) {
      List<ProjectEmployee> projectEmployeesToBeSaved = projectIdToProjectEmployeesMap.getOrDefault(projectEmployee.getProject().getId(), new ArrayList<>());
      projectEmployeesToBeSaved.add(projectEmployee);
      projectIdToProjectEmployeesMap.put(projectEmployee.getProject().getId(), projectEmployeesToBeSaved);
    }
    projects.forEach(project -> project.setProjectEmployees(projectIdToProjectEmployeesMap.get(project.getId())));
    return projects;
```

So, ye as you see im able to achieve my goal of getting all projects with their projectEmployees in a constant number of queries(2) and only select the fields i need. The downside is that i have a javacode running with O(n) complexity. But i reduced the size of the data im transmitting by over 90%, so i guess its worth.

It´s hard to believe that a java code algorithm like the one i used is required to find a solution for my problem, so if anyone finds a better solution(with just sql queries) which is capable of doing the above stated, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't verify it for your case, but at a first glance you may take advantage of the first level cache. After you perform

```java
List<Project> projects = projectRepository.findAllMinimal();
List<ProjectEmployee> projectEmployees = projectEmployeeRepository.findByProjects(projects);
```

Any access to `projectEmployee.getProject()` should return its project from the cache avoiding n+1 problem. So if you can leave `project.projectEmployees` List unpopulated, you can drop your "custom javacode".

Comment: I tried that and that did not work for me, i am not sure whether that is because i´m only selecting a few properties and not the entire project with `findAllMinimal()`.

Comment: Well, the last assumption is easy to check.